# getting max value from alias in DB2

Tags: database, db2

I wanna searching for max value in my alias. this is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT IPK.NIM,IPK.NAMA,IPK.IPK
FROM MAHASISWA M, PENILAIAN P, MATA_KULIAH MK, KRS K,
(SELECT M.NIM,M.NAMA, ROUND(SUM(P.ANGKA*MK.SKS)/SUM(MK.SKS),2) AS IPK
FROM MAHASISWA M, PENILAIAN P,MATA_KULIAH MK,KRS K
WHERE M.NIM=K.NIM AND MK.KODE_MK=K.KODE_MK AND K.NILAI=P.NILAI GROUP BY M.NIM,M.NAMA
) AS IPK
WHERE IPK.IPK=(SELECT MAX(IPK.IPK) FROM IPK);
```

But when I run it, it says DB2ADMIN.IPK was not found. How I can search it from my own alias in my query?

Comment: It's not recommended to use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax; please always explicitly qualify your joins.  Among other things, it makes it more obvious when you forget conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IPK.NIM,IPK.NAMA,IPK.IPK
    FROM MAHASISWA M, PENILAIAN P, MATA_KULIAH MK, KRS K,
    (
        SELECT M.NIM,M.NAMA, ROUND(SUM(P.ANGKA*MK.SKS)/SUM(MK.SKS),2) AS IPK
           FROM MAHASISWA M, PENILAIAN P,MATA_KULIAH MK,KRS K
           WHERE M.NIM=K.NIM AND MK.KODE_MK=K.KODE_MK AND K.NILAI=P.NILAI 
           GROUP BY M.NIM,M.NAMA
           ORDER BY IPK DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY               
    ) AS IPK;
```

This will cause the inner query to only return the maximum row.

Here is how to get the average `IPK` for each:

```
SELECT IPK.NIM,IPK.NAMA, AVG(IPK.IPK)
    FROM MAHASISWA M, PENILAIAN P, MATA_KULIAH MK, KRS K
    (
        SELECT M.NIM,M.NAMA, ROUND(SUM(P.ANGKA*MK.SKS)/SUM(MK.SKS),2) AS IPK
           FROM MAHASISWA M, PENILAIAN P,MATA_KULIAH MK,KRS K
           WHERE M.NIM=K.NIM AND MK.KODE_MK=K.KODE_MK AND K.NILAI=P.NILAI 
           GROUP BY M.NIM,M.NAMA

    ) AS IPK
    GROUP BY IPK.NIM,IPK.NAMA;
```

Comment: How if I wanna searching average value from IPK?

Comment: @blueboyz, in that case, return all the rows and add grouping to your outer query.  See update.

Comment: I mean for all of mahasiswa, not for each